# pthread_create recovery when error is occurred

Tags: c, loops, pthreads

I'm creating threads in while loop. But when I don't have neccessary memmory for new thread, error EAGAIN is occurred. How to pragmatically wait for resources.

Here is code segment

```
while(1){               
    if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, method, (void*)parameters) != 0){
        perror("error");
        ----> here new attempt for creating thread
    }
}
```

thx for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to pragmatically wait for resources.

When `pthread_create()` fails with `EAGAIN`, it says "Insufficient resources to create another thread.".

So, you can wait a bit before attempting again. But how long to wait for? Is the wait time can be the same across different systems with different resources? There can't be any generic strategy in such situations.

Usually you *don't* want to create threads in an infinite loop (like you do with `while(1)` loop). One common strategy is to use [thread pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) in which you create a fixed number of threads which repeatedly do a task. You can decide the number of threads based on the system resources (number of processors available for example).

If you need the threads to do certain tasks and exit then you can create the threads in a *detached state* so that so that the thread-specific resources are cleaned up automatically when threads exit (default state is *joinable*) and thus more resources are available for subsequent thread creations. In addition, you can also *limit* the number of active threads at any time.

It all depends on the nature of your application. Fundamentally, you have to *design* your application in such a way that you neither overload the system with too many threads nor under-utilize the system with fewer threads than your system can actually manage.

Comment: Agreed. I might add that for the specific case of thread pools, and user specified number of threads in the thread pool, it is best to abort and let the user know that the desired number of threads could not be started. For a heuristic or guessed number of threads, I'd decide a minimum (number of threads that should be available) and the desired number, and only abort if there are fewer than the minimum number of threads available. Finally, the default stack size on most systems is huge, typically 8M, and is often the limiting factor; using `pthread_attr_t` to decrease that is often useful.